# Armazenamento local com React Native

Tags: react-native

Estou criando uma aplicação que necessita armazenar alguns dados localmente. São dados simples como por exemplo um caminho de "Rota" para requisição HTTP, ou um campo com um "tempo" que será utilizado para a aplicação fazer uma ação.

Sabendo isto podem me dizer qual é a forma que consigo salvar esses dados?

Como referência seria algo como ter um arquivo de preferencias no android ou banco SQLite onde eu guardaria uma série de dados básicos que são utilizados como configuração da aplicação.

Não entendi bem a aplicação do AssyncStorage pois dentre os dados que preciso salvar está um "array".

Saberiam me ajudar com essa questão?

Comment: Se você precisar de algo relacional, e não queira usar o AsyncStorage pode experimentar o [RealmDB](https://realm.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o AsyncStorage para armazenar localmente todos os tipos de dados.

Para variaveis básicas podes simplesmente inserir no *setItem* para armazenar

```
var someText = "abc";
await AsyncStorage.setItem('someTextName', someText);
```

para buscar a informação podes usar o getItem

```
var someText = await AsyncStorage.getItem('someTextName');
```

Para casos onde precisas de armazenar objetos ou arrays podes usar JSON para guardar da seguinte forma:

```
var someArray = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
await AsyncStorage.setItem('someArrayName', JSON.stringify(someArray));
```

para buscar a informação basta fazer parse de volta para o objeto, assim:

```
var someArrayString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('someArrayName');
var someArray = JSON.parse(someArrayString );
```